# JavaScript Change img src automatically

Tags: javascript, prompt

## Problem

I am almost complete with my project, but I have yet another problem which I can't figure out. I need to have the image `src` change automatically when a prompt box closes. Here is what I mean.

## Example

Lets say I have this code.

### HTML

```
<button id="begin" onClick="javascript:fight();">Begin</button>
<img id="scenario" src="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/stage1.png">
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
function fight()  {
  var img = document.getElementById("scenario");
  var start = document.getElementById("begin");
  img.src = "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/map.jpg"; /* This changes it when the function is called */
  var decision1 = function()  {
    var decision = prompt("What do you do now? ATTACK, SLEEP, or PASS?").toUpperCase();
    if(decision === "ATTACK")  {
      attack();
    }
    if(decision === "SLEEP")  {
      sleep();
    }
    if(decision === "PASS")  {
      skip();
    }
  }
```

## Question

How can I change the src of an img automatically when a (the) prompt dialog box closes? Or, check whether it's open or not?

## What I tried

- Putting `img.src =
  "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/stage1.png";` after the
  `fight()` function
- Trying a check like this: `if(fight() === true)  { img.src =

  "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/stage1.png"; }`
- Adding a 'refresh' function, but it breaks the code.

## Things to Note

- I know that my JavaScript in the example will probably seem wrong,
  because I did a syntax wrong or there's no `attack()`, `sleep()`, or
  `skip()` function. Well, this is just an example so I'm not posting
  my whole game code here, which is about 1000 lines long.
- I'll post a snippet with the code provided above, and a JSFiddle
  with the actual project with the full code for better
  troubleshooting.

```js
function fight() {
  var img = document.getElementById("scenario");
  var start = document.getElementById("begin");
  img.src = "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/map.jpg"; /* This changes it when the function is called */
  decision1();
  var decision1 = function() {
    var decision = prompt("What do you do now? ATTACK, SLEEP, or PASS?").toUpperCase();
    if (decision === "ATTACK") {
      attack();
    }
    if (decision === "SLEEP") {
      sleep();
    }
    if (decision === "PASS") {
      skip();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="scenario" src="http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/stage1.png">
<button id="begin" onClick="javascript:fight();">Test</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d8sxxykj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function fight()  {

  var start = document.getElementById("begin");
  var decision1 = function()  {
    var img = document.getElementById("scenario");
    var decision = prompt("What do you do now? ATTACK, SLEEP, or PASS?").toUpperCase();
    if(decision === "ATTACK")  {
    img.src = "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/map.jpg";
    attack();
    }
    if(decision === "SLEEP")  {
    img.src = "something.jpg";
    sleep();
    }
    if(decision === "PASS")  {
    img.src = "something.jpg";
    skip();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would it change it back to the `stage1.png` picture when the prompt box closes?

Comment: `img.src="something"` will be exectuted once the prompt is closed.

Comment: Change `something` with the `url` of `image`

Comment: Ah okay. I'll test this real quick, and if it works, I'll 1up + accept as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

`$("#scenario").attr("src", "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/stage1.png");`

instead of

`img.src = "http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/stage1.png";`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not aware of jQuery yet, plus it interferes with the mixing of the JavaScript.